# Libgdx, collision, 2 rectangles, rotation, noob

Tags: java, android, libgdx

Here is my problem,

I have  2 rectangles.
I want to detect collision between these 2 rectangles.
However one rectangle should be able to rotate around a given position(player midpoint,not constant).

My Problem is, that i don't know how to rotate this one [Rectangle](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/math/Rectangle.html).

I would be grateful for any help.

Here is a sketch of my problem:

[image]

for a simple collision detection I had always rectangles:

```
playerrect = new Rectangle(playerposition.x,playerposition.y,playersizeX,playersizeY);
enemyrect = new Rectangle(enemyposition.x,enemyposition.y,enemysizeX,enemysizeY);
```

and this;

```
if(playerrect.overlaps(enemyrect)){.....}
```

and this was enough for me.
This time this noob needs the playerrect at various angles, like 5°,10°,15°.....
So I need something like

```
playerrect.setRotation
```

which is not available :).

Comment: Please add also a sample of code you already have.

Comment: I tried to add some code but I don't really have a code for that. What I need is an advice or an idea how to do it .

Comment: LibGDX `Rectangle` isn't made for that, there is also nothing for collision detection in this case. You'll have to make your own `RotatableRectangle extends Rectangle` I think.

Comment: Good Idea @noone, i tried it but its like making polygons. so I decided to try it with polygons instead of rectangles

Answer (score 2):

Libgdx [Rectangle](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/math/Rectangle.html) can't do that unfortunately. If you want that kind of collision detection, the easier way would be using [Box2d](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Box2d).